# gpiozero : Not working, no error messages

Tags: raspbian-stretch, gpiozero

I can't make gpiozero to work. Here is my config:
raspbian on raspberry 3B V1.2

> $ python -V

return: python 2.7.13

> $ python3 -V

return: python 3.5.3

which mean that I have several version of python and that the one running is 2.7.13

> $ pintout

this command works which min gpiozero is installed I guess (and I installed it again anyway following the doc recommandations)

Here are the tutorials I have been working with https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/burping-jelly-baby/
and this one : http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html
Absolutly no chance. the programme is running but no burp or no led turning on. I did check the pin and tried both BCM or pin number.
I also tried this one : https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/ultrasonic-theremin/ and had the same problem so I finally used the rpio.gpio which worked ! So the problem doesn't come from the raspberry pi.

I have tried to run the programme under ptyhon3.5.3 IDLE and Thonny and the terminal. no luck

I did several apt-get update && upgrade. 
I tried to make it run on another raspberrypi with a fresh raspbian-stretch installed. Same issue. I obviously miss something…

Anyone get an idea ? where, what should I dig to find a solution ? 
thanks
K.

Comment: Rather than point to tutorials please choose one complete (small) script and add it your question.  What happens when you run that one complete (small) script and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: As joan says start with something simple like the flashing LED http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#led If it doesn't work post you code and photo of your wiring.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help. The problem came from a dysfunctional wire.
I realized it as I was doing what you have asked for (photo of my set up and post of my code). For the purpose of the photo I changed a wire to a different color and the led turned on. I tried the other programme and everything is smooth.Thanks a lot